# Scraping value from field on a page

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a page that has a link like this:

```
<a id="something" href="place" class="thing" data="12345">
<span class="otherthing"></span></a>
```

I'd like to extract the number in the field called data. I've been trying to use BeautifulSoup like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        if 'data' in a['a']:
                print a['a']['data']
```

But I'm getting a key error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is what you need:

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if a.has_attr('data'):
        print(a['data'])
```

Answer (score 1):

To get only `<a>` elements that have `data` attribute:

```
data = [a['data'] for a in soup.findAll('a', data=True)]
```

To keep only those elements that contain an integer in the `data` attribute:

```
import re

data = [int(a['data']) for a in soup.findAll('a', data=re.compile(r"^\d+$"))]
```